# Oracle query found issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
select product.id,product.name,product.itemcode,sum(product.amount)as total_amount
from product where product.account in
select G.account from  report_results G 
where     G.status='Y')
group by product.id,product.name,product.itemcode
```

Consider the above as QUERY1

Now in order to perform an operation i modified the QUERY1 as below(i am using a new table called proc_temp

```
 (select product.id,product.name,product.itemcode,sum(product.amount)as total_amount
   from product where product.account in
   (select G.account from  report_results G 
   where     G.status='Y'))as Input,proc_temp
   where Input.id=proc_temp.id
```

The above query is not correctly formed.I want to join query1 with a new table proc_temp
and compare both of its id column.Please help me in correcting this syntactically.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `SELECT` clause. I can't vouch for this query since I don't know what you want to do, but something like:

```
select i.*
from (
    select product.id, product.name, product.itemcode, sum(product.amount) as total_amount
    from product
    where product.account in (
            select G.account
            from report_results G
            where G.status = 'Y'
            )
) i
inner join proc_temp t on i.id = t.id
```

Comment: @paul `i.id` comes from the derived table immmediately after the first `from` keyword

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the subquery, and use an inner join.
Besides that, the following query assumes that Input.id is G.account

```
select p.id,p.name,p.itemcode,sum(p.amount)as total_amount
from product p
inner join report_results g on (p.account = g.account)
inner join proc_temp pt on (g.account = pt.id)
where g.status='Y'
group by product.id,product.name,product.itemcode
```

Comment: @Carlos.Thanks for the response